# Which data sent by telnet when user press any key

Tags: linux, keypress, telnet

I want to know that which data telnet send when user press any key like <kbd>Esc</kbd>,<kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F12</kbd>,<kbd>tab</kbd>,<kbd>enter</kbd>,<kbd>shift</kbd>  keys? Are they ascii value of keys ?

Answer (score 0):

yes when we clicked buttons of keyboard telnet send data as ascii value of button.
This is not the case, however, because there are other network virtual terminal (NVT) rules, such as the requirement for a bare carriage return character (CR, ASCII 13) to be followed by a NULL (ASCII 0)